# Data retrieval and download

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

How to download the data which is displayed on windows forms that is retrieved from the database in the form of columns and rows? I want to download the data in a Word format. Can anyone help with this, please? This is the code which I used to retrieve the data

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();

    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=MYPC\\MSSQLSERVERNAVEN;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True;";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from login_details1";

    con.Open();

    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    BindingSource bg = new BindingSource();
    bg.DataSource = dr;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = bg;

    con.Close();
}
```

So what is the code to download the data in doc format?

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do, and what you already tried

Answer (score 0):

To get .doc you'd have to run the app interactively as the user and use interop.

What you can do easily, though, is use OpenXml SDK: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=5124

Then you can do:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument =
WordprocessingDocument.Create(@"C:\folder\file.docx", WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
        {
            var p = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();
            p.Document = new Document();
            Body body = p.Document.AppendChild(new Body());
            Paragraph para = body.AppendChild(new Paragraph());
            Run run = para.AppendChild(new Run());
            run.AppendChild(new Text("Hello, world!"));
        }
```

To find out how to do tables follow this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc850841(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following . which creates the Datagridview data in in the form of Table in the word document.

It relies on the Interoplibrary ' Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word '

Either you can use datagridview or preferbaly use the data source it self to create the Table in word

[Check this link](http://www.cprogramdevelop.com/4892520/)